# Может ли тривиальный класс выбрасывать исключения?

Tags: c++, классы, исключения

Что означает конструкция `noexcept(false) = default`? Как класс может быть одновременно тривиальным и выбрасывать исключения?

```
#include <type_traits>

struct A {
    A() noexcept(false) = default;
};

static_assert(std::is_trivially_default_constructible_v<A>);
static_assert(not std::is_nothrow_default_constructible_v<A>);
```

Comment: В GCC валится второй ассерт.

Comment: **Note that a noexcept specification on a function is not a compile-time check; it is merely a method for a programmer to inform the compiler whether or not a function should throw exceptions. The compiler can use this information to enable certain optimizations on non-throwing functions as well as enable the noexcept operator, which can check at compile time if a particular expression is declared to throw any exceptions.**

Comment: Это не конструкция, это сочетание двух механизмов. default тут никаким боком

Comment: @megorit я и не говорил, что это один механизм. Как класс может быть одновременно тривиальным и выбрасывать исключения?

Comment: А если класс имеет данные-члены, он уже не тривиально-конструируемый?

Comment: @megorit https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible

Comment: Все non-POD данные-члены конструируются (инициализируются) как бы перед телом конструктора, но всё равно эта инициализация является частью конструктора. И они могут кидать исключения напрмиер. Вот и всё.

Comment: @megorit и для них не будут выполнятся ассерты из вопроса...

Comment: @lasqa, я вообще не понял, что такое тривиально-конструируемый. Фигня какая-то бесполезная если честно. Зачем оно вообще пригодится может? Добавил мув конструктор - перестал быть таковым, добавил данные с конструктором - тоже. Т.е. это будет работать только для аггрегатов из PODов и типов-тегов... Нафига....

Comment: Судя по всему не может, потому что если он содержит тело дефолтного конструктора, он уже не тривиальный, содержаит не тривиальный член - тоже не тривиальный, наследуется - не тривиальный. Значит просто бросать неоткуда. По сути это либо метафункция, либо тип-тег. Не представляю зачем нужны такие проверки.